# Watch every next line while debugging in Intelij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I was wondering if there is any way in Intellij to know the output of the next line while debugging?

Sometimes errors occur in the next line for which I have to use expression elevator to see what kind of error, error message etc.

Watching(or evaluating) every next line and showing the result before hand without breaking the flow would be helpful.

Any setting, any plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Evaluate expression? In case ob exception you will see it but debug mod won't be stoped

Comment: I was talking about the evaluate expression mode itself.
I'm looking for something like automatic evaluate expression of the next line continuously, so that I need not press Ctl + U every time I want to see what would happen in the next line